# Who designs and controls Unity?

Tags: unity

which people are in charge and control over Unity? are those the same people that decide to use it in different versions of Ubuntu?

- Who owns it?
- who controls what will be in it?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you're looking to put a hit out on someone ;)

Comment: I just found a brown paper bag, and had no idea on what else to do.

seriously, I've heard that GNOME makes Unity. And others have told me that canonical makes it and just throws it into GNOME. please explain this.

Comment: FYI The Gnome Foundation has nothing to do with Unity. Whoever told you that was trolling you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unity is a [Canonical](http://www.canonical.com/) product. Canonical controls both Ubuntu and Unity.

**UPDATE** (after tumbleweed's comment):

"*Canonical controls Ubuntu*" (1) vs. "*Canonical does not control Ubuntu development*" (2).

Well, truth(tm) is probably somewhere in the middle. It's worth to mention about the [Ubuntu Fundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Foundation) which was founded by Mark to make Ubuntu more Canonical independent.

Anyhow, Ubuntu will probably never be as community controlled as Debian is,
but I don't think it's bad. I think what Mark and Canonical do is really good.
IMHO, Mark should get a Nobel prize for his attitude and accomplishments for the human race.

Comment: It's not that simple. Canonical is the majority contributor to Ubuntu and Unity, but doesn't control Ubuntu Development.

Comment: @tumbleweed: Very interesting comment. I updated the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I think Canonical *wants* to be the majority Ubuntu contributor, but also run Ubuntu as an open project. Ubuntu's project governance strives to be independent from Canonical, but Canonical funds a large chunk of Ubuntu development and infrastructure.

Comment: who is this "Mark"?

Comment: @Alvar: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Shuttleworth

Answer (score 1):

From the [Unity Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/unity):

> Designed by Canonical and the Ayatana community, Unity is all about the combination of familiarity and the future.

Have a look at the [Unity Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/unity) for more information.

Comment: -1, this A. doesn't answer the question and B. is almost as bad as a "Just go google it.".

Comment: So quoting the page is good, linking the page isn't? I'd rather link to a page which will be updated if needed, than quote qome stuff here which might get changed tomorrow and future readers will get incorrect or incomplete information.

Comment: Linking to the page with a quote is good. However, what you originally had was "here is the launchpad project, go read that." - anyone can say that, it takes a real answer to say "Here's what it says, and here are my sources.".

Comment: Halt there! I never was impolite or abrupt in my answer, "Go read that" is something I didn't say. Still, quoting 1 line and linking so the user has to read that link anyway is better than just give the link, stating all information is on there? That's just a waste of my time and the readers time.

Answer (score 1):

Unity is an open source project created at Canonical and like Ubuntu can be packaged with other distributions although I don't know of anyone else including Unity as a default desktop in their distribution yet but have it as an option. Control seems like such a strong term to be used in the context of open source. Oracle tried that with OpenOffice and it was forked along with the development team into LibreOffice. In the open source world you can lead, contribute and support a package but there are no patents or ownership that gives any individual or company control past the influence that comes with participation and support.

Answer (score 1):

Unity and Ubuntu are both Canonical products. They are pieces of sotfware developed by Canonical Ltd. You can contribute in their development either by filing bug reports, solving bugs, translating the software, etc on Launchpad.net, which is a collaboration and hosting platform for software projects owned by Canonical, or you can also share your opinion, propose new ideas and vote your favourite ones about Ubuntu and its interface, Unity, on Ubuntu Brainstorm page:

http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://design.canonical.com/2012/02/the-unity-design-process-and-how-you-can-play-a-part-in-it/) is about unity, how it's designed and how you participate in it, I think it explains My main question very well.